# Adding else if conditional statement to purchased theme

Tags: php, conditional-tags, header-image

I purchased a theme that I want to change a bit. I'm familiar with writing some if/else statements but not this type and not matter what I do, I can't add an else/if without breaking the code.

Below is the code from the theme...

```
<?php
   if (!is_404() && !is_attachment()) {
      if (is_singular() || is_page('gallery') || is_page('about') && has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) && ($image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'post-thumbnail') ) && $image[1] >= HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH) :
          echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'post-thumbnail' );
      else : ?>
          <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH; ?>" height="<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
<?php endif; } ?>
```

The code shows a featured image as a banner on the pages where there is one. I am trying to write an else/if statement that doesn't show the featured image as a banner on the single post pages, and like I said, every time I try adding an else/if, I end up breaking the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditional for posts is `is_single()`. So …

```
if ( ! is_404() && ! is_attachment() && ! is_single() ) {
    # rest of the code
}
```